# If state is true than run this component

Tags: reactjs

ComponentDidMount will update my component every second(with setInterval) but I want it to update only if my state is true ,is something of that sort is possible?

Comment: `componentDidMount` only runs once when the component is mounted. Please provide an actual example of what you are talking about.

Comment: I have setInterval which updates it every Second sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: @karrijayanth Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` instead and renew timeout only if "state is true"

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.start()
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.stop()
}

start() {
  this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
     doSmthUseful();

     if(state is true) { // whatever you mean by "if my state is true"
         this.start()
     }
  }, 1000)
}

stop() {
   clearTimeout(this.timeoutId)
}
```